# How to fix validation summary message not getting refreshed when keep SetFocusOnError as true

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using two asp.net validation controls 1. RequiredFieldValidator & 2. RegularExpressionValidator for my password textbox to validate the user input and set its display property to none so that valiadation message will only get displayed in validationsummary control.

when I click on submit button the validation get displayed as expected but when I use SetFocusOnError as true for both validators sometimes the validation message doesn't get refreshed for ex. if there is no text entered in the text box and click on submit button it display required field validation message but when enter any text and click on submit button it still display required field validation instead of RegularExpressionValidator validation message but when click submit button next time it propertly display
RegularExpressionValidator validation message

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPass"  CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"
                        meta:resourcekey="txtPassResource1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPass" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtPass"
                        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Enter Password" ValidationGroup="submit"
                        meta:resourcekey="rfvPassResource1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 <div class="password_error" style="width:auto;">
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rxvalPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password should be at least 6 characters in length. It should have at least one numeric and one special character from ~ ! @ # $ & _ . * "
                            ControlToValidate="txtPass" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[~!@#$&_.*])[A-Za-z0-9~!@#$&_.*]{6,15}$"
                             ValidationGroup="submit" Display="none" meta:resourcekey="SpecialCharResource2" />

</div>

 <div class="rows col-md-offset-5">
                <div class="width12">
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valnewuser" runat="server" ValidationGroup="submit" meta:resourcekey="valnewuserResource1" EnableClientScript="True" />
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="col-md-offset-6"> 
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidatePage();" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                    ValidationGroup="submit" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmitResource1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do test it again as when I reviewed and tested your code, it worked perfectly fine.
The error showed as per validation. If still some anomaly happens, do show that exact code.